# Unique from-to combination with all the duration after it in variable loop

Tags: python, bash, algorithm, sorting, csv

I have a problem with getting info from a log file compressed with the uniques brought together in a loop in BASH or Python.

I have a huge log file, I do a grep on it to find the info of a specific country to get only the unique "from street,city" and the "to street,city" and duration of the trip in csv format.

Also to and from the same street to the same street with the same duration is counted but is shown as 1 entry with the count of hits.

I also managed to sort them so that it sorts on first on the same "from street" and second the "to street".

But what I want is to have the same from-street, to-street, with all the different durations after it.

INPUT CSV:

```
 from-street,from-city,destination-street,destination-city,duration
 Street1,City1,Street2,City2,30min
 Street1,City1,Street2,City2,10min
 Street1,City1,Street2,City2,15min
 Street1,City1,Street3,City3,28min
 Street1,City1,Street3,City3,20min
 Street1,City1,Street3,City3,5min
 Street2,City2,Street4,City4,12min
```

OUTPUT VARIABLES that need to get looped:

```
$from-street,$from-city,$destination-street,$destination-city,$duration1,$duration2,$duration3
Street1,City1,Street2,City2,30min,10min,15min
Street1,City1,Street3,City3,28min,20min,5min
Street2,City2,Street4,City4,12min
```

I hope that someone could help me with this, since I made the first extended grep command and put the uniques in csv format, I'm stuck with the next part, what is stated above.

Maybe Bash is the preferred way because you can directly use the grep before the loop in 1 smooth script. But I'm also trying to learn Python, so it is also more than welcome.

Thank you guys

Comment: What is your extended grep command? Do you have an example of a good and bad match?

Comment: It is a zgrep over different days of zipped logs, there I manipulate the data with SED, to then CUT only the fields I need and then replace the spaces again with comma. to have the CSV format. Then get the COUNT and SORT it based on from-address and to-address.

So really nothing fancy, al the hits on this grep or a good match, so the grep command with all the piping works great and I don't have bad matches. I just need them to get the distances together like in the example.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In Python*, you may create a `tuple` of `Street1, City1, Street2, City2` as a key to your `dict` object and use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to append the values.

When you will read your *csv* file, the content you will get will be as list like:

```
my_csv = [ ['Street1', 'City1','Street2','City2','30min'],
           ['Street1', 'City1','Street2','City2','10min'],
           ['Street1', 'City1','Street3','City3','28min']]
```

Then your code to store the values in desired format will be:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = defaultdict(list)

for item in my_csv:
    my_dict[tuple(item[:4])].append(item[4])
```

Final value hold by `my_dict` will be:

```
{
     ('Street1', 'City1', 'Street2', 'City2'): ['30min', '10min'], 
     ('Street1', 'City1', 'Street3', 'City3'): ['28min']
}
```

*Note:* Dictionaries are un-ordered by nature. Hence, you will loose the order of occurrence of the line.

Comment: Hi Moinuddin,

Looks like a great solution, but if I understand you correcly I loose the ordering? 

Maybe I have to clear something up.


The output of the grep is actually like this with a count in front, without a comma.


`
Count from-street,from-city,destination-street,destination-city,duration

5230   Street1,City1,Street2,City2,30min

2114   Street1,City1,Street2,City2,10min

1221   Street1,City1,Street3,City3,28min `